# Plotly: How to utilize meta argument for functions such as go.Scatter?

Tags: python, plotly

**The essence:**

How can I use `%{data[0[.meta[0]}` from the output of `help(go.Scatter)` in the context of the following setup?

---

Consider a simple plotly scatter plot such as this:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = [1,2,3]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=t, mode='lines'))
fig.show()
```

Running `help(go.Scatter)` will give an output in which the following can be found:

```
 |      meta
 |          Assigns extra meta information associated with this
 |          trace that can be used in various text attributes.
 |          Attributes such as trace `name`, graph, axis and
 |          colorbar `title.text`, annotation `text`
 |          `rangeselector`, `updatemenues` and `sliders` `label`
 |          text all support `meta`. To access the trace `meta`
 |          values in an attribute in the same trace, simply use
 |          `%{meta[i]}` where `i` is the index or key of the
 |          `meta` item in question. To access trace `meta` in
 |          layout attributes, use `%{data[n[.meta[i]}` where `i`
 |          is the index or key of the `meta` and `n` is the trace
 |          index.
```

**Question:**

I just can't make sense of the following part:

> To access trace `meta` in layout attributes, use `%{data[n[.meta[i]}`
>   where `i` is the index or key of the `meta` and `n` is the trace
>   index.

In this particular plot, there's ***one*** trace, accessible for example by running `fig['data'][0]`:

```
Scatter({
    'mode': 'lines', 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [1, 2, 3]
})
```

Judging by other information about `meta` in the help file, I thought that accessing this would empower us to edit the text attributes for for example `sliders` and `label` since it's stated that

> Attributes such as trace `name`, graph, axis and colorbar
>   `title.text`, annotation `text` `rangeselector`, `updatemenues` and
>   `sliders` `label` text all support `meta`.

I've tried various approaches like `fig['%{data[0[.meta[0]}']` but I suspect I've misunderstood the entire concept completely. Could anyone please give an example of how to utilize the meta argument in this context?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a type error in the help file. I think it should be: `%{data[n].meta[i]}`.

The following code sets the figure title attribute:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

meta = ["My Figure 1", "Data"]
t = [1,2,3]
data = go.Scatter(x=t, 
                  y=t, 
                  mode='lines')
layout = {'meta': meta,
          'title': '%{meta[0]}' }

fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

Or you put the `meta` data in a trace:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

meta = ["My Figure 1", "Data"]
t = [1,2,3]
data = go.Scatter(x=t, 
                  y=t, 
                  mode='lines',
                  meta= meta)
layout = {'title': '%{data[0].meta[0]}' }

fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

In both cases the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering! Looking forward to testing it out!

Comment: A friendly reminder to accept and upvote the answer. It's of great importance for the Plotly-Dash project that correct answers are marked as such (especially when typing errors in the help function are concerned). Thank you